# Kdb/q example of http client with authentication

Tags: kdb

Is it possible to use Kdb+ http client to access pages protected by login? I am using https://github.com/KxSystems/cookbook/blob/master/yahoo.q as example of basic GET/POST. Does anyone have an example how to extract a cookie and use it in the following requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably a bit crude, but the following will extract headers from an http, then cookies, parse and return as a dictionary:

```
x:"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nSet-Cookie: theme=light\r\nSet-Cookie: sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT\r\n\r\n";


left:{(first y ss x)#y};
vs1:{{(y#x;(count[z]+y)_x)}[y;;x](first y ss x)};
headers:{{(`$x[0];x[1])} flip vs1[": "] each 1_"\r\n" vs left["\r\n\r\n"]x};
cookies:{(!). {(`$x[0];x[1])} flip vs1["="] each {x[1]@where x[0]=`$"Set-Cookie"} x};

cookies headers[x]
```

Comment: A bit of knitpicking: a header field value can span multiple lines: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2

Comment: Agree with nitpicking and can also add one more - there is no requirement for a space after colon, in fact it can be any whitespace or none at all. I might try to fix those when I have time, but will just leave as a comment for now.

Comment: Interestingly, `.z.ph` is passed a request header as a dictionary, i.e. there is code to parse HTTP headers. I wonder can one make use of this code somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you might be able to various bits and bobs from an http response, the fact that you won't be able to manipulate http methods means that q can't be your tool to do this - well, not without some vigorous effort.

I would use something like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) in conjunction with q. Soup has some great tools for handling this kind of thing (e.g. cookies etc). There are various other similar projects too.

System call for Beautiful Soup that make relevant get/post/put calls and download required data

```
system"/path/to/code.py"
```

Where the code dumps the result somewhere or puts it into kdb directly. Then do whatever you like with it.